# Magento 2 admin page menu and buttons didnt work after speed optimization

Tags: magento2, javascript

After we enable javascript bundling and minify javascript files, admin left menu and buttons didnt work. Also in our website we could add products to the basket.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Hi @Mabita, Could you please share the error logs during admin page load? You can get the logs from var/logs or you can get the error from the browser console.